# How to use InboundClaimTypeMap for claim mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, thinktecture-ident-server

I have similar problem as here : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/issues/9

But solution is not helpful for me.

So lets explain in more details with pictures and code:

**I have this on client:**

[image]

No need to map because NameClaimType(RoleClaimType) and Claim in list of claims are same

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

**On Api project I have:**

[image]

In this case (if I understand correctly), I have to to map, because NameClaimType & RoleClaimType are not same with claim values.

```
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"role", System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role},
        {"name",System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name }
    };
```

But still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InboundClaimTypeMap is used to transform the incoming claims. It doesn't set the `NameClaimType` and `RoleClaimType` properties.

Your authentication middleware should have the option to set name and role claim types. For instance:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
  new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
      ...,
      NameClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name,
      RoleClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role 
    });
```

Comment: This is great, this code resolved problem that I have for few days. Thanks!
But still is not clear to me in what case to use 'InboundClaimTypeMap'? If you could explain me in some simple example.

Comment: As for the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.inboundclaimtypemap(v=vs.114).aspx), it will map incoming claim's type property to the mapping value of the dictionary. So in your example mapping, if the incoming token has claim of type "role" it will be mapped to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" in your ClaimsPrincipal

Comment: A use case for this is described in https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html Claims transformation section

Comment: I have never used AddIdentityServerAuthentication myself, I instead always use AddOpenIDConnect to secure the client and AddJwtBearer to secure the API. see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html and https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html