# Local validation of IdentityServer

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I have Auth Service hosted on some url. All my microservices requested validation to auth on each requests. In  StartUp.cs of each services I have

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerURL"],
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,

            //ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local,
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "user-api" },
        });
```

It works fine! And in my controller's method in this case I have as you can see

> {role: consumer}

[image]

But if I change

> ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local,

My request doesn't pass Authorization because values of roles has prefixes
[image]

And according to this my request doesn't pass autorization. What should I do in case

> ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local

to have normal value of claims role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft apply a claims mapping when the token is received. To remove this default mapping, add this to your Configuration method at startup:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

For more information:

[How to use InboundClaimTypeMap for claim mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622624/how-to-use-inboundclaimtypemap-for-claim-mapping)

[Update of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt causing breaking change in IdentityServer3 Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080608/update-of-system-identitymodel-tokens-jwt-causing-breaking-change-in-identityser)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was helped!)